# Error running .jar on Ubuntu: Could not find ot load main class

Tags: ubuntu, java

I'm creanting an script to run an .jar on Ubuntu 18.

The project was develop on Windows with Intellij IDEA.

In windows the .jar runs correctly.

But in Linux is show the error:

```
Could not find or load main class br.com.insper.agil.LinuxScriptsJava
```

cmd used: **java -jar etc/profile.d/jar/LinuxScriptsJava.jar**

- **MANIFEST.mf:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: br.com.insper.agil.LinuxScriptsJava
```

The project is not using external .jar libs.

I need to add some classpath commands in MANIFEST file to run in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default java version in ubuntu 18 is java 11.

So I used this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6) to change the version to java 8. And now it's running.

- Basically the solution was the commands to change the default jdk:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javaws" 1
```